# How to remove stopwords from common words list in python

Tags: python, list

I want to know how to remove stop words from most common words list. I want to get only words. The example structure is as below:

```
sentence = [('the', 2112), ('and', 1914), ('to', 1505), ('of', 1086), ('a', 986), ('you', 912), 
     ('in', 754), ('with', 549), ('is', 536), ('for', 473), ('it', 461), ('book', 427), 
     ('how', 368), ('that', 347), ('as', 304), ('on', 301), ('this', 290), ('java', 289), 
     ('s', 267), ('your', 263), ('applications', 248), ('web', 231), ('can', 219), 
     ('new', 218), ('an', 206), ('are', 197), ('will', 187), ('from', 185), ('use', 185), ('ll', 183), 
     ('development', 182), ('code', 180), ('by', 177), ('programming', 172), ('application', 170), ('or', 169), 
     ('action', 163), ('developers', 150), ('features', 141), ('examples', 139), ('learn', 135), ('using', 132), 
     ('be', 132), ('data', 131), ('more', 118), ('like', 115), ('build', 110), ('into', 109), ('net', 106), ('language', 105)]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the meaning of "stop words"

Comment: You will need a list of stop words and then you can filter them out.

Comment: Also, @Larissa, I'd recommend you checking out `ntlk` if your intent is to make natural language processing. `nltk` has a built-in list of hundreds of stop words in more than one language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first create a *set* of stop words, and then you could use something like the following to filter them out:

```
>>> stopList = {'the','and','to','in'}
>>> [(word, count) for word, count in sentence if word not in stopList]
```

Comment: you should create a `set`, `O(1)` lookup time, not `O(n)`

Comment: @acushner of course, thank you! I've edited my answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want a good full set of stop words you could use the list available in nltk as follows:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

sentence = [('the', 2112), ('and', 1914), ('to', 1505), ('of', 1086), ('a', 986), ('you', 912), 
     ('in', 754), ('with', 549), ('is', 536), ('for', 473), ('it', 461), ('book', 427), 
     ('how', 368), ('that', 347), ('as', 304), ('on', 301), ('this', 290), ('java', 289), 
     ('s', 267), ('your', 263), ('applications', 248), ('web', 231), ('can', 219), 
     ('new', 218), ('an', 206), ('are', 197), ('will', 187), ('from', 185), ('use', 185), ('ll', 183), 
     ('development', 182), ('code', 180), ('by', 177), ('programming', 172), ('application', 170), ('or', 169), 
     ('action', 163), ('developers', 150), ('features', 141), ('examples', 139), ('learn', 135), ('using', 132), 
     ('be', 132), ('data', 131), ('more', 118), ('like', 115), ('build', 110), ('into', 109), ('net', 106), ('language', 105)]

sentence = [(word, count) for word, count in sentence if word not in stop_words]     

print sentence
```

This would give you `sentence` as:

```
[('book', 427), ('java', 289), ('applications', 248), ('web', 231), ('new', 218), ('use', 185), ('development', 182), ('code', 180), ('programming', 172), ('application', 170), ('action', 163), ('developers', 150), ('features', 141), ('examples', 139), ('learn', 135), ('using', 132), ('data', 131), ('like', 115), ('build', 110), ('net', 106), ('language', 105)]
```

You can use `pip install nltk` to get the library. You may then need to first install the stop words as follows:

```
import nltk

nltk.download()
```

This will display a download utility allowing you to get the stopwords as follows:

[image: nltk stopwords installation]

Answer (score 0):

set will get the search result in O(1) and out_tup will have required output

```
in_tup = [('the', 2112), ('and', 1914), ('to', 1505)]
stop_list = {"to","the"}

out_tup = [i for i in in_tup if i[0] not in stop_list]
print out_tup
```